# Deserializing a JSON into a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, deserialization

I have a string in a Java server application that is accessed using AJAX. It looks something like the following:

```
var json = [{
    "adjacencies": [
        {
          "nodeTo": "graphnode2",
          "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
          "data": {
            "$color": "#557EAA"
          }
        }
    ],
    "data": {
      "$color": "#EBB056",
      "$type": "triangle",
      "$dim": 9
    },
    "id": "graphnode1",
    "name": "graphnode1"
},{
    "adjacencies": [],
    "data": {
      "$color": "#EBB056",
      "$type": "triangle",
      "$dim": 9
    },
    "id": "graphnode2",
    "name": "graphnode2"
}];
```

When the string gets pulled from the server, is there an easy way to turn this into a living JavaScript object (or array)? Or do I have to manually split the string and build my object manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse json in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 447, accepted):

Modern browsers support `JSON.parse()`.

```
var arr_from_json = JSON.parse( json_string );
```

In browsers that don't, you can include [the `json2` library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Comment: How that will work for date fields in JSON, for instance 
{StartDate: "\/Date(1372575600000)\/"}?

Comment: @PhilippMunin you could use this Date function from the javascript API :
new Date(parseInt("/Date(946681200000)/".replace('/Date(', '')));

Comment: or Map() objects etc, how do you do _proper_ deserialisation

Answer (score 27):

The whole point of JSON is that JSON strings can be converted to native objects without doing anything. Check this [link](http://www.json.org)

You can use either `eval(string)` or `JSON.parse(string)`.

However, `eval` is risky. From json.org:

> The eval function is very fast.
>   However, it can compile and execute any JavaScript program,
>   so there can be security issues.
>   The use of eval is indicated when the source is trusted and competent.
>   It is much safer to use a JSON parser.
>   In web applications over XMLHttpRequest,
>   communication is permitted only to the same origin that
>   provide that page, so it is trusted.
>   But it might not be competent.
>   If the server is not rigorous in its JSON encoding,
>   or if it does not scrupulously validate all of its inputs,
>   then it could deliver invalid JSON text that could be carrying dangerous script.
>   The eval function would execute the script, unleashing its malice.

Comment: I don't understand the risk. Can't anyone use a js debugger to inject and execute any script they want anyway?

Comment: @xr280xr Yes, but that happens only locally in their browser, not every browser that downloads the website.

Answer (score 17):

Do like jQuery does! (the essence)

```
function parseJSON(data) {
    return window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ? window.JSON.parse( data ) : (new Function("return " + data))(); 
}
// testing
obj = parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert(obj.name);
```

This way you don't need any external library and it still works on old browsers.

Comment: This looks like it's falling back to the equivalent of `eval()`.

Comment: This is dangerous, eval is evil!

Answer (score 11):

You could also use `eval()` but `JSON.parse()` is safer and easier way, so why would you?

**good and works**

```
var yourJsonObject = JSON.parse(json_as_text);
```

I don't see any reason why would you prefer to use `eval`. It only puts your application at risk.

That said - this *is* also possible.

**bad - but also works**

```
var yourJsonObject = eval(json_as_text);
```

**Why is `eval` a bad idea?**

Consider the following example.

Some third party or user provided JSON string data.

```
var json = `
[{
    "adjacencies": [
        {
          "nodeTo": function(){
            return "delete server files - you have been hacked!";
          }(),
          "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
          "data": {
            "$color": "#557EAA"
          }
        }
    ],
    "data": {
      "$color": "#EBB056",
      "$type": "triangle",
      "$dim": 9
    },
    "id": "graphnode1",
    "name": "graphnode1"
},{
    "adjacencies": [],
    "data": {
      "$color": "#EBB056",
      "$type": "triangle",
      "$dim": 9
    },
    "id": "graphnode2",
    "name": "graphnode2"
}]
`;
```

Your server-side script processes that data.

**Using `JSON.parse`:**

```
window.onload = function(){
  var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder1');
  placeholder.innerHTML = JSON.parse(json)[0].adjacencies[0].nodeTo;
}
```

will throw:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position X.
```

Function will not get executed.

**You are safe.**

**Using `eval()`:**

```
window.onload = function(){
  var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder1');
  placeholder.innerHTML = eval(json)[0].adjacencies[0].nodeTo;
}
```

will execute the function and return the text.

If you run this on the serwer side and I replace this harmless function with one, that removes files from your website folder or does something harmful, then your app will get hacked. No errors/warnings will get thrown in this example.

**You are NOT safe.**

I was able to manipulate a JSON text string so it acts as a function which will execute on the server.

`eval(JSON)[0].adjacencies[0].nodeTo` expects to process a JSON string but, in reality, we just executed a function on our server.

This could also be prevented if we server-side check all user-provided data before passing it to an `eval()` function but why not just use the built-in tool for parsing JSON and avoid all this trouble and danger?

Comment: Thank you for this. I believe this is #8 in OWASP web app risks, Deserialisation.

Comment: I agree eval is bad, but wouldn't you have to write `.nodeTo()` with parentheses for it to execute as a function?

Answer (score 8):

TO collect all item  of an array and return a json object

```
collectData: function (arrayElements) {

        var main = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayElements.length; i++) {
            var data = {};
            this.e = arrayElements[i];            
            data.text = arrayElements[i].text;
            data.val = arrayElements[i].value;
            main[i] = data;
        }
        return main;
    },
```

TO parse the same data we go through like this

```
dummyParse: function (json) {       
        var o = JSON.parse(json); //conerted the string into JSON object        
        $.each(o, function () {
            inner = this;
            $.each(inner, function (index) {
                alert(this.text)
            });
        });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

And if you also want the deserialised object to have functions, you could use my small tool: https://github.com/khayll/jsmix

```
//first you'll need to define your model
var GraphNode = function() {};
GraphNode.prototype.getType = function() {
   return this.$type;
}

var Adjacency = function() {};
Adjacency.prototype.getData =n function() {
    return this.data;
}

//then you could say:
var result = JSMix(jsonData)
    .withObject(GraphNode.prototype, "*")
    .withObject(Adjacency.prototype, "*.adjacencies")
    .build();

//and use them
console.log(result[1][0].getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you paste the string in server-side into the html don't need to do nothing:**

For plain java in jsp:

```
var jsonObj=<%=jsonStringInJavaServlet%>;
```

For jsp width struts:

```
var jsonObj=<s:property value="jsonStringInJavaServlet" escape="false" escapeHtml="false"/>;
```

Answer (score -3):

I think this should help:

Also documentations also prove that you can use require() for json files:
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2908-you-can-use-require-to-load-json-javascript-object-notation-files-in-node-js.htm

```
var jsonfile = require("./path/to/jsonfile.json");
node = jsonfile.adjacencies.nodeTo;
node2 = jsonfile.adjacencies.nodeFrom;
node3 = jsonfile.adjacencies.data.$color;
//other things.
```