# Serialization of javascript function for c#

Tags: c#, javascript, json, javascriptserializer

In my c# class I have the following class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int product_id;
    public int quantity;
    public string book_cost;
}
```

If I serialize it with `JavaScriptSerializer` then I get back

```
{"product_id":0,"quantity":0,"book_cost":"hello"}
```

after setting the values.

Thats c#, but how could I serialize a javascript function to match this?

I am wanting to parse a js function into a c# class

Example.... if I had a class in c# and I wanted to send it to some other webserver, I could serialize the object and make it into JSON using

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(new Product());

public class Product
{
   public int product_id = 0;
   public int quantity = 0;
   public string book_cost = "hello";
}
```

then on the other side i could have this:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Product p = serializer.Deserialize<Product>(products);
Console.WriteLine(p.product_id);

public class Product
{
   public int product_id;
   public int quantity;
   public string book_cost;
}
```

and it would print out 0 because I created a new product class with those values from the other class, however I want one side to be js (the sending side) and the other to be c# (the receiving side)

here is more of an example:

js side...

I have this function, I have set the values to this, but I would change them at runtime.

```
function Product(){
    this.product_id = 0;
    this.quantity = 0;
    this.book_cost = "hello";   
}
```

then I would want to generate from this I would want to generate

```
{"product_id":0,"quantity":0,"book_cost":"hello"}
```

Then on the other side I would want to populate the Product class that is above. I am only going to be using strings, integers, and date objects. If I serialize a DateTime object in c# it comes out to be

```
{"date":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"}
```

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserialize-from-json-to-javascript-object

Comment: not duplicate. This is serializing a js function TO JSON not parsing JSON

Comment: Also, I want to parse a js function to c# function

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: @SmartLemon - I think what you're looking for is the [ASP.NET Ajax Framework](http://www.asp.net/ajax), though you could also use WCF.  Both will serialize between JavaScript objects and C# objects, allowing you to work with data between both tiers.

Comment: jrummell isnt the op ^ xD. Also example up.

Comment: Are you looking for [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)?

Comment: Ok now I'm even more confused..

Comment: im so confused by what you want?

Comment: Writing more of an example now

Comment: @SmartLemon - If you're trying to generate proxy objects, you can't really do that from a JSON string as it doesn't include full type information.  What you might be looking for is WSDL, which can describe an interface contract for a web service.  ASP.NET is capable of generating proxies in both C# and Javascript from a WSDL file.

Comment: Have a look at my new edit to see what I want xD.

Comment: @SmartLemon - Looks fine to me.  As long as the fields all match up, you can deserialize JSON generated from a JavaScript object to a class in C#.  Is there something specific that isn't working with what you have?

Comment: The question is HOW do I serialize it.

Comment: @SmartLemon - On the JavaScript side?  Just use [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (Note: Many JavaScript frameworks also have JSON helper functions)

Comment: That comes back with `{"product_id":0,"quantity":0,"book_cost":"","date":"2012-12-18T21:57:30.479Z"}` I guess this is fine. I will just format the date into the right format and parse it at the other side :). Could you put it in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize an object in JSON using the [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method.  Something like:

```
function Product() {
    this.product_id = 0;
    this.quantity = 0;
    this.book_cost = "hello";   
}

var p = new Product();
p.quantity = 5;
var json = JSON.stringify(p);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NsdRt/)

Don't worry about date formats.  Any good serializer is will be able to recognize various representations of dates.  There should be no need to *reformat* anything by hand.