# JSON Array - Extract Data With Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json

I have a really simple Json array and I need to get back

- the number of items within the array.
- the list of entries in order of the id.

The array is as follows:

```
{"error":false,"error_msg":"","body":
{"records":[{"name":"Application","id":1},
            {"name":"Fees Paid","id":2},
            {"name":"Evidence Verification","id":3},
            {"name":"Details QA","id":4},
            {"name":"Grade Approval","id":5},
            {"name":"Welcome Pack","id":6}]
},
"validation_errors":[]}
```

Comment: by within the array you mean within `records`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [deserialize from json to javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserialize-from-json-to-javascript-object)

Comment: `body.records.name.length -> I need a `foreach statement to list out the names in order of their ids. The array is returned into a function as data therefore `data.body.records.name` has also been tried

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON array". JSON is a string.

Comment: You're going to need to just loop over (parsed json data).records and then do work with records[i].id and records.length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have `JSON.parse`d your string into a variable called `jsonobj`, the following statements get the data you want:

```
var len = jsonobj.body.records.length;
jsonobj.body.records.sort(function(a,b) {return a.id-b.id;});
// now iterate through jsonobj.body.records and they will be in ascending ID order
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have your *Object* held in variable `jObj`, clone the *Array/Objects* so you preserve the originals, `sort` it as desired then return an *Array* which just holds the *name* properties.

```
jObj['body']['records']
    .map(function (e) {return {'id': e['id'], 'name': e['name']};}) // clone
    .sort(function (a, b) {return +a['id'] - +b['id'];})            // sort asc
    .map(function (e) {return e['name'];});                         // get names
/* [
    "Application", "Fees Paid",      "Evidence Verification",
    "Details QA",  "Grade Approval", "Welcome Pack"
] */
```