# how to convert a string to an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, object

I would like to know how to convert the string below to an object in Javascript:

```
var string = '{"id":"50","actor":"1","subject":"1","object":"18","message":"a ajout\u00e9","status":"unseen"}'
```

In fact, I would like that after converting the string above to an object, I will be able to access to any element of that object. For example, if I convert the string to an object called "obj" I will be able to access to the value of the element "id" (which is "50") in such way: obj.id

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The linked question used for closing is totally obsolete. If you're not happy with my answer below use this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserialize-from-json-to-javascript-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This string is in [JSON](http://json.org/).

Use

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

Comment: This *must* be a duplicate...