# JSON access variable field

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to write a library for Riot (League of legends API) in NodeJS and I have the following problem.

I'm doing:

```
function getSummonerProfile(sum) {
    var summoner = sum.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    request("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"
            + summoner + "?api_key=" + api_key, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
}

getSummonerProfile("some player");
```

the console shows:

```
{
    "player": {
        "id": 37842773,
        "name": "player",
        "profileIconId": 548,
        "summonerLevel": 30,
        "revisionDate": 1368783726000
    }
}
```

Now "`player`" is a variable (function parameter); how can I access the data? to get for example, only the `id`.

`body.summonner` and `body["player"]` throw `undefined`.

EDIT 1 (complete code):

```
var request = require("request");
var api_key = 'example';

function getSummonerProfile(sum) {
    var summoner = sum.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    request("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"
            + summoner + "?api_key=" + api_key, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body.summoner.id);
    });
}

getSummonerProfile("some player");
```

Comment: I've tried: Undefined

Comment: In that case you're doing something wrong. Show exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit with the whole code.

Comment: Check the spelling of `summonner`. This looks incorrect.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but just a pointer: you should use encodeURIComponent on the summoner variable and api key as you insert them into the API URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function getSummonerProfile only sends a request, using this request function which seems to be processing the internal part (console.log) when the request return with the data from server side. So basically you should save the data instead of the console.log line. You could bind it somewhere or save to a variable. And it seems that player is the body variable's key you are looking for.

Maybe something like this:

```
var request = require("request");
var api_key = 'example';
var summoners = {};

function getSummonerProfile(sum) {
    var summoner = sum.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    request("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + summoner + "?api_key=" + api_key, function(error, response, body) {
        summoners[summoner]=JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(summoners[summoner].player.id);
    });
}

getSummonerProfile("some player");
```

Comment: but console.log(summoner[summoner].id); gots me undefined :(

Comment: and console.log(summoner[summoner]?

Comment: if it displays the structure than yoiu0 should use this way the body: `summoner[summoner]=JSON.parse(body.player);`

Comment: if you use this way: `summoner[summoner]=JSON.parse(body); console.log(summoner[summoner].player.id;`?

Comment: summoner[summoner]=JSON.parse(body);
console.log(summoner[summoner].summoner.id);
TypeError: Cannot read property 'summoner' of undefined

Comment: If I do: console.log(summoners[summoner]["rklz"].id); (rklz) is my username it works!; but if i do console.log(summoners[summoner].summoner.id); it gets me undefined.

Comment: console.log(summoners[summoner][sum.replace(/\s+/g, '')].id); did the trick, thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Are you actually getting a JavaScript Object? You're probably getting a JSON string, you need to parse it back into a JavaScript Object...

```
var newdata = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(newdata.player.id);
```

Support is no worry, according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=JSON)

Answer (score 1):

if you have a variable like this

```
json_var = {
    "player": {
        "id": 37842773,
        "name": "player",
        "profileIconId": 548,
        "summonerLevel": 30,
        "revisionDate": 1368783726000
    }
}
```

you can do this to access the data

```
id = json_var["player"]["id"]
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking forever for a solution to this, I don't know how I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is JSON deserialization.

If you are using javascript, your question has an answer here: [deserialize from json to javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserialize-from-json-to-javascript-object)

If you are using another language, the principle is the same, you need to have a class that matches the fields of your JSON file and use a deserializer.

Comment: The response returns JSON object.
https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the response as a jsonstring. To get response as js object try this:

```
request({url: "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + summoner + "?api_key=" + api_key, json: true}, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body.player.id);
    });
}
```