# Export json data into html table following format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to export json data into html table in customize format.

```
 var data =[ { "ID":1, "Sl.No.":1, "325":25, "430":30, "2011":15, "1915":80 }, { "ID":1, "Sl.No.":2, "325":40, "430":30, "2011":20, "1915":100 }, { "ID":1, "Sl.No.":3, "325":40, "430":25, "2011":20, "1915":100 }, { "ID":1, "Sl.No.":4, "325":4, "430":2, "2011":1, "1915":20 }];
```

required output following format

`ID Sl.No.

1    1    0325    25
1    1    0430    30
1    1    2011    15
1    1    1915    80
1    2    0325    40
1    2    0430    30
1    2    2011    20
1    2    1915    100
1    3    0325    40
1    3    0430    25
1    3    2011    20
1    3    1915    100
1    4    0325    4
1    4    0430    2
1    4    2011    1
1    4    1915    20`

Comment: @taylorc93  I am new to json. i cant able to create logic for this code .

Comment: @Arthik have a go using a _native JavaScript Object_ first and see if you can get that working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data =[ { "ID":1, "Sl.No.":1, "325":25, "430":30, "2011":15, "1915":80 }, { "ID":1, "Sl.No.":2, "325":40, "430":30, "2011":20, "1915":100 }, { "ID":1, "Sl.No.":3, "325":40, "430":25, "2011":20, "1915":100 }, { "ID":1, "Sl.No.":4, "325":4, "430":2, "2011":1, "1915":20 }];
$a = $('#values')
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  $thisRow = $('<tr/>')
    .append($('<td>' + value['ID'] + '</td>'))
    .append($('<td>' + value['Sl.No.'] + '</td>'))
    .append($('<td>' + '0325' + '</td>'))
    .append($('<td>' + value['325'] + '</td>'))
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (i == 0)
      key = '430';
    if (i == 1)
      key = '2011';
    if (i == 2)
      key = '1915';
    $thisRow = $('<tr/>')
      .append($('<td>' + value['ID'] + '</td>'))
      .append($('<td>' + value['Sl.No.'] + '</td>'))
      .append($('<td>' + key + '</td>'))
      .append($('<td>' + value[key] + '</td>'));
    $a.append($thisRow);
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="values"></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Try parsing the json string to javascript object array (Ref:
   [deserialize from json to javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserialize-from-json-to-javascript-object))
2. Use for loop to iterate through each array value and create a table
   html as you require
3. Append the html into your html doc using jQuery
   append (Ref: http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```js
var data ='[{ "ID":1, "Sl.No.":1, "325":25, "430":30, "2011":15, "1915":80 }, { "ID":1, "Sl.No.":2, "325":40, "430":30, "2011":20, "1915":100 }, { "ID":1, "Sl.No.":3, "325":40, "430":25, "2011":20, "1915":100 }, { "ID":1, "Sl.No.":4, "325":4, "430":2, "2011":1, "1915":20 }]';

var str = JSON.parse(data);
var temp= '';

$.each(str,function(index, value){

  var id = value.ID;
  var slNo = value['Sl.No.'];
  
   $.each(value, function(ind, val){
   
       if(ind !='ID' && ind != 'Sl.No.' )
                  temp+='<tr><td>'+id+'</td><td>'+slNo+'</td><td>'+ind+
                    '</td><td>'+val+'</td></tr>';             
   });
});

$('#myTable tbody').append(temp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <thead>
      <th>Head 1</th>
    <th>Head 2</th><th>Head 3</th><th>Head 4</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
```