# How can I get simple data from JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How can I get the value from this object?

```
var descipt = "{'type':'" + $('#medi-type option:selected').val() +"',"+
        "'weight':" + $('#weight').val() +","+
        "'weight-type':'" + $('#weight-type option:selected').val() +"',"+
        "'dose':'" + $('#medicine-dose').val() +"',"+
        "'dose-type':'" + $('#dose-type option:selected').val() +"',"+
        "'day-time':'" + morning +"',"+
        "'noon-time':'" + noon +"',"+
        "'night-time':'" + night +"',"+
        "'after':'" + after +"',"+
        "'before':'" + before +"'}";

alert(descipt.weight);
```

how to get weight from the object.

Comment: var jsonObj = JSON.parse(descipt);
var weight = jsonObj.weight;
var weighttype = jsonObj["weight-type"];

and so on...

Comment: I don't get the point of doing this. You can simply create a object instead of a string.

Comment: You can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zvw0zgw3/2/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing a JSON into a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserializing-a-json-into-a-javascript-object)

Comment: If you want to work with the object, why even bother with JSON? Just create an object directly...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not a JSON object, that's a string.
You should first parse it to a JSON object with

```
var desciptObject = JSON.parse(descipt);
```

and then you can read weight with

```
weight = desciptObject.weight;
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to convert that to a JavaScript object with:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(descipt);
```

and after that use like this:

```
alert(obj.weight);
```

in fact this is an string and you can not access like a object to nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.parse

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(descipt);
var weight = jsonObj.weight;
var weighttype = jsonObj["weight-type"]; // jsonObj.weight-type  will throw error
```