# How to use Javascript Array String in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string

I am getting one Javascript Array from `HttpRequest` as below :

```
"var time[0] = '2019-11-23 20:11:12'; var plate[0] = 'DK01A11511'; var path[0] = '/LPR/2019112404111200.jpg'; var region[0] = ''; var direction[0] = '28'; 
    var roi_id[0] = '-92'; var plate_left[0] = '0'; var plate_top[0] = '0'; var plate_right[0] = '0'; var plate_bottom[0] = '0'; 
var time[1] = '2019-11-23 20:11:12'; var plate[1] = 'BR01AN1511'; var path[1] = '/LPR/2019112404111201.jpg'; var region[1] = 'o.0'; var direction[1] = '0'; 
    var roi_id[1] = '0'; var plate_left[1] = '29486'; var plate_top[1] = '11887'; var plate_right[1] = '48'; var plate_bottom[1] = '12334'; 
var time[2] = '2019-11-23 20:11:55'; var plate[2] = 'BR01DD0621'; var path[2] = '/LPR/2019112404115500.jpg'; var region[2] = 'o.0';  var direction[2] = '0'; 
    var roi_id[2] = '46'; var plate_left[2] = '12846'; var plate_top[2] = '11776'; var plate_right[2] = '28531'; var plate_bottom[2] = '12846'; 
var time[3] = '2019-11-23 20:12:03'; var plate[3] = 'BR01PG5254'; var path[3] = '/LPR/2019112404120300.jpg'; var region[3] = ''; var direction[3] = '0'; 
    var roi_id[3] = '0'; var plate_left[3] = '0'; var plate_top[3] = '0'; var plate_right[3] = '0'; var plate_bottom[3] = '0'; 
var time[4] = '2019-11-23 20:12:11'; var plate[4] = 'BR01PB0909'; var path[4] = '/LPR/2019112404121100.jpg'; var region[4] = '���8j��'; var direction[4] = '145'; 
    var roi_id[4] = '84'; var plate_left[4] = '27192'; var plate_top[4] = '-18699'; var plate_right[4] = '0'; var plate_bottom[4] = '0'; 
var time[5] = '2019-11-23 20:12:17'; var plate[5] = 'BR01PK9977'; var path[5] = '/LPR/2019112404121700.jpg'; var region[5] = '����Pi��'; var direction[5] = '145'; 
    var roi_id[5] = '84'; var plate_left[5] = '27192'; var plate_top[5] = '-18699'; var plate_right[5] = '0'; var plate_bottom[5] = '0'; 
var time[6] = '2019-11-23 20:12:31'; var plate[6] = 'BR01PJ0443'; var path[6] = '/LPR/2019112404123100.jpg'; var region[6] = 'r�������(���(����������'; var direction[6] = '216'; 
    var roi_id[6] = '-118'; var plate_left[6] = '19008'; var plate_top[6] = '-18782'; var plate_right[6] = '0'; var plate_bottom[6] = '0'; 
var time[7] = '2019-11-23 20:12:32'; var plate[7] = 'BR01PJ0443'; var path[7] = '/LPR/2019112404123200.jpg'; var region[7] = ''; var direction[7] = '136'; 
    var roi_id[7] = '-119'; var plate_left[7] = '-13812'; var plate_top[7] = '-18709'; var plate_right[7] = '-22552'; var plate_bottom[7] = '-16732'; 
var time[8] = '2019-11-23 20:12:36'; var plate[8] = 'BR01PH9530'; var path[8] = '/LPR/2019112404123600.jpg'; var region[8] = ''; var direction[8] = '160'; 
    var roi_id[8] = '-77'; var plate_left[8] = '-19628'; var plate_top[8] = '-18698'; var plate_right[8] = '-19628'; var plate_bottom[8] = '-18698'; 
var time[9] = '2019-11-23 20:13:36'; var plate[9] = 'BR0BB6799'; var path[9] = '/LPR/2019112404133600.jpg'; var region[9] = 'd���'; var direction[9] = '96'; 
    var roi_id[9] = '-85'; var plate_left[9] = '-20966'; var plate_top[9] = '-16732'; var plate_right[9] = '21420'; var plate_bottom[9] = '1';"
```

Now I am trying to use this in C# by directly assign to Object but didn't got any success.

Can you tell me how to deserialize and use this? I want to use time, plate and path. I have tried to assign this string to Object and Var but nothing is working. Even array size is not fix so picking value from string using `substring` is also not working.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing a JSON into a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserializing-a-json-into-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Wait. hol up... what *sane* web request would return this. You will have to parse this your self, *why you have to* is another question entirely

Comment: I agrre with TheGeneral, is not possible to deserialize this kind of string, you must create yourself a code to parse this string (split)