# How to fetch sql server data to my react native app?

Tags: sql-server, reactjs, native

I have a problem in my application developed with react native and sql server .

In page X, I want to search by year and month
and display the results on the same page of the form,
For now I can display them only in an alert

This is my code :

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.12:80/fetch.php',{
   method:'post',
   header:{
   'Accept':'application/json',
   'Content-type' :'application/json'
   },
   body:JSON.stringify({email:usermail,password:password,})})
   .then((responseData)=>responseData.text()).then((responseJson)=>{
     alert(responseJson)})
   .catch((error)=>{console.error(error);})}
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.pass}>
            <Text style={{marginTop:20 , color:'grey'}}>Annee:</Text>
            <TextInput placeholder={this.state.placeholder1} style={{flex:1,paddingLeft:5}}
            onChangeText= {usermail=>this.setState({usermail })}/>
             </View>
            <View style={styles.pass}>
        <Text style={{marginTop:20 , color:'grey'}}>Mois :</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder={this.state.placeholder2} style={{flex:1,paddingLeft:5}} secureTextEntry={this.state.secureTextEntry}
        onChangeText= {password=>this.setState({password})}
        />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.butt} onPress={this.userRegister}>
                <Text>Afficher</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
```

The form that helps me to filter my data by year and month

[image]

the result of my query in alert

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

First, it might be useful to separate out this request from your component just for ease of debugging in the future! Can I suggest a separate service that handles your data access and returns a list of objects you construct from the returned JSON?

Second, you get `responseData` back and...alert on it. But you don't store that information off in a variable, or call render from inside that scope. The lambda function you're using knows what `responseData` means because it's seeing it passed in (`then((responseJson)=>{ alert(responseJson) })`), but how can `render()` know about this data if it isn't stored anywhere? Where would it reference it?

Start by [deserializing your JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserializing-a-json-into-a-javascript-object), and then do something with that data. At this point, you seem to be storing quite a bit in the state - I'm not going to lecture you on functional decomposition of components, but if you're following the pattern set by the rest of your application why not store it there?

Comment: this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        }, function(){
        });

Comment: Are you asking if that would work, or indicating that you've already tried this? That snippet of code isn't in your original post, and I'm at a loss for what you're trying to communicate by commenting it here.

Comment: Sorry if i made you lost !! but what I want to say is that I  know how to save my data (using dataState:responseJson inside setState) but I dont know how to pass this array to another page and show them into table

Comment: By page do you mean component? You can pass data between components as props - if this is the parent of your other page, you should be able to follow along here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html